# jssor slider Clips Images as it slides in and out only on firefox

Tags: jquery, jssor

I have a problem that I am trying to solve and need assistance with jssor slider. I have searched but have not been able to find something that relates to my issue. I have 6 images in jssor slider, all the same size. In firefox the first 3 images will slide in and out as expected. The 4th will slide in "clipped" like the top half of the image is visible, but the bottom is missing, but once the image has slid into place, the rest of the image is displayed fully, but gets clipped again as it slides off.

I thought it was something I did wrong, so I got a fresh copy of jssor and observed In firefox the js jssor examples have the same issue. I used slider with bullet navigator source example.

Is there a fix for this? It works in chrome and IE..

thanks.

I decided to swap in another slider called slippry to verify that the problem is with firefox, or jssor.. well, the slippry slider does the same thing as well. So I am thinking that firefox is to blame. You can see it here www.deviseconcepts.com.

I will be putting the jssor slider back on that page later when I get a chance. If anyone knows why this is happening to these jquery sliders please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know which one has the problem.

Comment: Please leave me a link of your page.

Comment: appended my findings to the initial post. The slider on that site is slippry slider, but the jssor behaves the same way in Firefox both on local host and on the web-server.

Comment: yes, this problem appears with firefox 35 only.